# How do I animate an attack for this game created in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

So I made made this code:

```python
def spear_atk(x,y):
    global spear_state
    spear_state="attack"
    screen.blit(spear,(x-20,y))

running=True

while running:
    screen.fill((0, 0, 50))
    screen.blit(bg, (0, 0))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            running = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                playerx_change = -2
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                playerx_change = 2
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                playery_change = -2
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                playery_change = 2
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                playerx_change = 0
                playery_change = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                spear_state = "attack"
                spear_atk(playerx,playery)
    playerx += playerx_change
    playery += playery_change
    player(playerx,playery)
    inamic(enemyx,enemyy)
    pygame.display.update()
```

And I want the spear attack to last a little bit longer. An n amount of time, for example. How do I extend the amount of time the spear is shown on screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
screen.fill((0, 0, 50))
screen.blit(bg, (0, 0))
```

So, each time through the loop, your plan is to redraw the entire scene.

Therefore, every time through the loop, *if you are still showing the animation*, you need to draw the spear. You use the `spear_state` that you set when the attack starts, to keep track of whether that's true.

So there are two issues now:

- You need to [control how long it takes to go through the loop](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/102586/locking-the-frame-rate-in-pygame).
- You need to decide how many times through the loop the animation will be active for, and keep track of how long the animation has already been active. You can do this in much the same way as with the existing `spear_state` - try using an integer value that represents how many more iterations ("frames", in game-dev talk) the animation will be active for; when it reaches zero, you skip drawing the spear, and change the state back.

You can do fancier animations by setting up multiple images of the spear in appropriate positions and using that frame counter to decide which one to draw (for example, by indexing into a list). This is easier to understand if you're familiar with the [underlying theory of animation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animation).